R shiny java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
When I run my shiny app via RStudio Server, either using the code from local dir or /srv/shiny-server, it runs smoothly, with success.
When I execute the app by calling the endpoint "10....:3838/app1" or by log in via terminal as root and execute the app R script, I get this error "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size" .
I get this error when trying to connect to the database, but no idea why it is happening, since the code is the same on local dir and /srv/shiny-server.
I would appreciate any help.
I tried to change permissions of files, like chmod and chown, but nothing happened.
I have also checked the decryption but the files and passwords are the same, it just gets an error when connecting to the DB.

I think the cause doesn't directly come from shiny. Have you tried the java part only ?  Have you done install.packages(c('rJava')) and before R CMD javareconf ? https://solutions.posit.co/envs-pkgs/using-rjava/ Read that also java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters in android (but IHMO not specific to android)

@phili_b thank you, your comment was useful. It made me think and explore other paths. I finally solved it.
I had to set the variable JAVA_HOME on the file /etc/profile to point to the correct folder
